# How to avoid being disconnected from the current socket.io connection when accessing other HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

```js
`var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var server = require('http').Server(app);

var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket.listen(server);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

var session = require('express-session')({
    secret: 'my_secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
});
var sharedsession = require('express-socket.io-session');
app.use(session);
io.use(sharedsession(session));

app.use(express.static('public'), function (req, res, next) {
    //req.accepts('html');
    next();
});




io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('new connection ' + socket.id);

    io.emit('socket', socket.id);

    socket.handshake.session.userdata = socket.id;
    socket.handshake.session.save();
});
```

`I am building a site using express, node, and socket.io. I am trying to implement a login page, different from the actual page.
How can resolve the problem that a user gets disconnected from the current socket.io connection when accessing the login page?

I've tried to implement express-session and express-socket-io-session for creating a session with the hope that the user will stay connected when he is trying to access the login page from the current page.

I would like to keep track the user connected into the socket.io connection during the time he accesses the login page and after he is logged in to be redirected to the main page.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: I added the server code.